# FastAPI calling a async Backgrounf function in Loop

Tags: python, fastapi, opc-ua

I use the FastApi Framework for Python in combination with the opcua-asyncio Library.

I want to Open a new "Connection" to listen to changes from the OPC Server.
For that i have the opc.py file with the Create Subscription function.

Everytime i call the Endpoint: "localhsost:8000/subscripe/"ip_address" the new Opc Client is added to the listening process.

I also want to close the Connection to every Server seperate from an API Call.
How can I achieve something like this ?

**opc.py**

```
import asyncio
from asyncua import Client, ua, Node

class SubscriptionHandler:
    """
    The SubscriptionHandler is used to handle the data that is received for the subscription.
    """
    def datachange_notification(self, node: Node, val, data):
        """
        Callback for asyncua Subscription.
        This method will be called when the Client received a data change message from the Server.
        """
        print('datachange_notification', node, val)

async def create_subscription(ip_address):
    client = Client(url='opc.tcp://'+ str(ip_address) + ':4840')
    async with client:
        handler = SubscriptionHandler()
        subscription = await client.create_subscription(50, handler)
        myvar = client.get_node("ns=4;i=11")
        await subscription.subscribe_data_change(myvar)

        while 1:
            await asyncio.sleep(0)
```

**app.py**

```
@app.get("/subscribe/{ip_address}")
async def subscribe(request: Request, ip_address: str):
    create_subscription(ip_address)
```

Comment: Yes, you can. Just need to await the create_subscription inside of subscribe

Comment: Its not working if i do so.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):     
  File "c:\users\felix\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1041, in create_connection
    sock = await self._connect_sock(
  File "c:\users\felix\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 955, in _connect_sock
    await self.sock_connect(sock, address)
  File "c:\users\felix\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\asyncio\selector_events.py", line 502, in sock_connect
    return await fut
asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError